# Changing Azure Devops Project Repo for a VS Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I have an existing Azure Devops Team Project (Project A).  I also have a Visual Studio solution on my local machine that I want to start tracking in Project A.

When I went to add my source code to Project A's repo from Visual Studio, I inadvertently created a new blank Team Project in Azure Devops (Project B).  So now I have two Team Projects.  Project A has all my work items, etc. and Project B has my source code.

In Visual Studio, I've tried editing the "Remotes" setting to the correct repo location, but that doesn't seem to have worked.  I went to *Team Explorer -> Settings -> Repository Settings -> Remotes -> Edit* to make the change.

I want to change my visual studio solution to publish my source code to Project A instead of Project B.

Comment: Are you using Git repositories or TFVC repositories?

Comment: I'm using TFVC at the moment.  I don't really care which one I use so long as I can manage everything in Azure Devops.

Comment: @TSoder you can create a new git repo in Project A then [push](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs-2017?view=vsts) your solution there, then delete the project B

Comment: @Jayendran Yes I was able to add my solution to an Azure Devops Repo.  However, I mistakenly added it to the wrong repo in a blank Team Project in Azure.  I would like to change my solution so I can push it to the correct repo.  I haven't been able to find a way to do that though.